# I-129 form in Portuguese

Tags: k1-visa

Were can I find a I-129 form in Portuguese? I will submit the I-129F online in English, but I would like to print out one in Portuguese or Spanish for my fiancée to read.

Answer (score 1):

The I-129F form for a US citizen to petition someone for a K-1 fiance visa or a K-3 visa is only available in English. You can translate it to another language yourself if you like.